# Sending Html page as body of Mail in php with variable values

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I have an html page uploaded on my server as payment_receipt.html;

I am using phpmailer to send an emai. This receipt i have to send as body of the Email.

Simply

```
$Content = file_get_contents("somefile.html"))
```

can do the trick.
However i need to set values like Amount, Client name etc.
They are placed inside html as

```
<div class="customerName">Dear{Customer Name}</div>
            <div class="confirmation">This email confirms your purchase of following services:</div>
```

Etc.

How can i set these values in my html before sending it as a body of mail.?

Comment: If you're set on including a static page like that then look into `str_replace()` http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: You can use `str_replace` and replace all those data within html which have     {such_format} with values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always know what the strings you need to replace will be, run a str_replace or similar on $Content

```
$Content = str_replace('{Customer Name}', $replacement_variable, $Content);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with multiple variables

```
$newText = str_replace(["{Name}", "{Adress}"], ["Charles", "Street X"], $oldText);
```